# Linked List with multiple variables in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a ToDo List project using linked list as its data structure. I encounter problem when in my addTask() in my header file in the line:

```
if (head != NULL)
{
    current = head;
    while (current->link != NULL)
    {
        current = current->link; //error happens here
    }
    current->link = n; //another error here
}
```

- '=' cannot convert from 'list*' to 'list::taskPTR'
- '=' cannot convert from 'list::task*' to 'list*'

^^^are the error that occurs. I don't understand my error and how to fix it.

here is the full header file:

```
#ifndef linkedList
#define linkedList

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class list
{
private:
    struct task
    {
        string taskDue;
        string taskDesc;
        string taskCourse;
        string day;
        string mon;
        string year;
        list* link;
    };

    typedef struct task* taskPtr;

    taskPtr head;
    taskPtr current;
    taskPtr temp;

public:

    list();
    ~list();
    void printByDue();
    void printByCourse();
    void printByStatus();
    void addTask(string addTaskDue, string addTaskDesc, string addTaskCourse, string addDay, string addMon, string addYear);
    void delTask(string delTaskDue, string delTaskDesc, string delTaskCourse, string delDay, string delMon, string delYear);

};


list::list() //constructor
{
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void list::addTask(string addTaskDue, string addTaskDesc, string addTaskCourse, string addDay, string addMon, string addYear)
{
    struct task* n = new task;
    n->link = NULL;

    n->taskDue = addTaskDue;
    n->taskDesc = addTaskDesc;
    n->taskCourse = addTaskCourse;
    n->day = addDay;
    n->mon = addMon;
    n->year = addYear;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        current = head;
        while (current->link != NULL)
        {
            current = current->link;
        }
        current->link = n;
    }
    else
    {
        head = n;
    }
}

void menu()
{
    char option;
    cout << " Welcom to the ToDo List Program by ACGR";
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "What would you like to do? \n" << endl;
    cout << "\t[a]dd a new task" << endl;
    cout << "\t[c]omplete a task" << endl;
    cout << "\t[d]isplay tasks" << endl;
    cout << "\t[q]uit" << endl;

    cout << "\nEnter choice here: ";
}
#endif // !linkedList.h
```

Comment: The error is explicit, what don't you understand ? Your pointers are of different types. `list*` for the `link` member and `task*` for the `head` variable (hint: `link` should be of type `task*` as well). Unrelated: you don't need to write `struct` in your `typedef`, this is C++ not C ;)

Comment: Unrelated, your class does not obey the rules of 0/3/5.

Comment: The `temp` member is useless, and a "proof" of that is that you does not even use it.

Comment: When you need to write new/delete it might be a good time to look into STL containers first. Thus Instead of writing your own list, why not use std::list. Also give task a constructor so you don't have to initialize each member seperately like n->taskDue = addTaskDue. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/constructors/

Comment: `list* link;` should be `task* link;`. A `list` is the entire list, and each `task` is a node in that list.

Comment: And don't make your local variables into members just to save on typing. It will only cause pain and confusion.

Comment: You need to seperate your concerns better. You have a list, and you have tasks. One has no reason to be nested in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack, but the likely simple fix is to change the following line:

```cpp
list* link;

// Should be

task* link;
```

Your tasks shouldn't be pointing to lists (they are in a list), they are supposed to be pointing to the next task in the list.

I will say that all this might do is reveal more errors, both logical and syntactical.

**However**, I would feel bad sending you on your way with that code. What you posted is not great, and for a great many reasons. I would have expected almost everything I'm going to demonstrate to have been taught by the time a linked list is assigned; it is in my curriculum.

Here's a mini-code review of what was posted:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// Where is <string> ? Include what you use.

using namespace std;  // Bad practice, **especially** in a header

class list
{
private:
    struct task  // A task has nothing to do with a list
    {
        string taskDue;
        string taskDesc;
        string taskCourse;
        string day;
        string mon;
        string year;
        list* link;  // This has nothing to do with a task.
                     // And now you've forced yourself to include Rule of 5 in your task.
    };

    typedef struct task* taskPtr;  // Subjective; I prefer `using taskPtr = task*;`
                                   // More subjective; I wouldn't do this at all.
                                   // taskPtr is longer than task*, I fail to see the point.

    taskPtr head;     // Prefer default member initialization.
    taskPtr current;  // Likely part of the todo list, which has no bearing on a list data structure
    taskPtr temp;     // ??? Why should a temp get permenant residence as class data?

public:

    list();
    ~list();
    void printByDue();  // Should be getters. Let the caller print if and how they want.
    void printByCourse();
    void printByStatus();

    // If the task and list were separate from each other, this could be simplified quite a bit.
    void addTask(string addTaskDue, string addTaskDesc, string addTaskCourse, string addDay, string addMon, string addYear);
    void delTask(string delTaskDue, string delTaskDesc, string delTaskCourse, string delDay, string delMon, string delYear);

};

// Use the initializaton section of constructors, or better yet default member initialization.
list::list() //constructor
{
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

//
// Where is the destructor? This shouldn't be compiling at all
//

void list::addTask(string addTaskDue, string addTaskDesc, string addTaskCourse, string addDay, string addMon, string addYear)
{
    struct task* n = new task;
    n->link = NULL;

    n->taskDue = addTaskDue;
    n->taskDesc = addTaskDesc;
    n->taskCourse = addTaskCourse;
    n->day = addDay;
    n->mon = addMon;
    n->year = addYear;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        current = head;
        while (current->link != NULL)
        {
            current = current->link;
        }
        current->link = n;
    }
    else
    {
        head = n;
    }
}

// This function has no business being here at all.
void menu()
{
    char option;
    cout << " Welcom to the ToDo List Program by ACGR";
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "What would you like to do? \n" << endl;
    cout << "\t[a]dd a new task" << endl;
    cout << "\t[c]omplete a task" << endl;
    cout << "\t[d]isplay tasks" << endl;
    cout << "\t[q]uit" << endl;

    cout << "\nEnter choice here: ";
}
```

The thing that will help you the most is to separate your concerns. A todo list and a linked list are separate entities and should be treated as such. A linked list uses nodes to link data together in a list-type way. A todo list is a list of tasks, and while I did use the word list there, I could write a todo list using an array, a stack, a queue, or even a hash-map. The underlying data structure can be pretty flexible depending on the desired functionality of the list.

So write the linked list, and then incorporate it into your todo list. This makes testing easier, focuses your code, and is just better practice.

For this assignment, the hard part is the list. Here's a quick and dirty one:

```cpp
#ifndef SINGLY_LINKED_LIST
#define SINGLY_LINKED_LIST

#include <utility>  // std::swap

template <typename T>
class SList {
 public:
  SList() = default;
  SList(const SList& other);
  SList(SList&& other) noexcept;
  ~SList();

  void add(T val);
  void erase(T val);

  // Employing copy-swap idiom; that's why the parameter is taken by value
  SList& operator=(SList rhs);

  friend void swap<>(SList<T>& lhs, SList<T>& rhs);

  // This function is for convenience and demonstration; I don't want to be
  // bothered implementing the minimal iterator required for a range-based
  // for loop.
  void print() const;

 private:
  struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node(T d) : data(d) {}
  };

  Node* head = nullptr;
  Node* tail = nullptr;

  // Helper
  std::pair<Node*, Node*> find_node_and_before(T val);
};

// Implementation
template <typename T>
SList<T>::SList(const SList& other) {
  Node* walker = other.head;
  while (walker) {
    add(walker->data);
    walker = walker->next;
  }
}

template <typename T>
SList<T>::SList(SList&& other) noexcept : SList() {
  swap(*this, other);
}

template <typename T>
SList<T>::~SList() {
  while (head) {
    Node* tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete tmp;
  }

  tail = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
void SList<T>::add(T val) {
  if (!head) {
    head = new Node(val);
    tail = head;
    return;
  }

  tail->next = new Node(val);
  tail = tail->next;
}

template <typename T>
void SList<T>::erase(T val) {
  auto toBeErased = find_node_and_before(val);

  if (toBeErased.second == head) {
    Node* tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete tmp;

    return;
  }

  (toBeErased.first)->next = (toBeErased.second)->next;
  if (toBeErased.second == tail) {
    tail = toBeErased.first;
  }
  delete toBeErased.second;
}

template <typename T>
SList<T>& SList<T>::operator=(SList rhs) {
  swap(*this, rhs);

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void swap(SList<T>& lhs, SList<T>& rhs) {
  using std::swap;

  swap(lhs.head, rhs.head);
  swap(lhs.tail, rhs.tail);
}

template <typename T>
void SList<T>::print() const {
  Node* walker = head;
  while (walker) {
    std::cout << walker->data << ' ';
    walker = walker->next;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename T>
std::pair<typename SList<T>::Node*, typename SList<T>::Node*>
SList<T>::find_node_and_before(T val) {
  if (head->data == val) {
    return {nullptr, head};
  }

  Node* walker = head;
  while (walker->next) {
    if (walker->next->data == val) {
      return {walker, walker->next};
    }
    walker = walker->next;
  }

  return {nullptr, nullptr};
}

#endif
```

Note that there is nothing to do with a todo list or tasks in it. It is just a linked list, as it should be. It can be a `SList<int>`, `SList<std::string>`, or any other type.

There are dependencies on that other type, like having an `operator<<()`, but that's mostly due to the print() function that normally wouldn't be there at all. It's included as a hack to demonstrate the list working.

I put together a super simple "task list" as well.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "slist.hpp"

struct task {
  std::string name;

  task() = default;
  task(const char* t) : name(t) {}
};

bool operator==(const task& lhs, const task& rhs) {
  return lhs.name == rhs.name;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sout, const task& t) {
  return sout << "\"" << t.name << "\"";
}

int main() {
  SList<task> one;
  one.add("trash");
  one.add("dishes");
  one.add("walk the dog");
  one.add("tidy up");

  one.print();
  one.erase("dishes");
  one.print();
  one.erase("tidy up");
  one.print();
  one.erase("trash");
  one.print();
}
```

Output:

```
"trash" "dishes" "walk the dog" "tidy up" 
"trash" "walk the dog" "tidy up" 
"trash" "walk the dog" 
"walk the dog"
```

By the time anyone is ready to write a linked list, nothing in my code should be new. Linked lists are a "dense" assignment that require the learner to be able to properly utilize almost every technique and principle that they've learned up to this point. I consider them the graduation out of "beginner"-level C++.

Two major principles that are missing and can be added include iterators and perfect forwarding (to write emplace functions).

Comment: One thing to add is that using the exact same API as other containers (like those from the STL) is really beneficial: it allows generic algorithms to work on your own containers as well. For example, instead of `add()`, name it `push_back()`, and your own container is then compatible with [`std::back_inserter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Comment: Great point! I normally do that when demonstrating a linked list, but I opted to keep the names the same as OP's this time, for reasons.

Answer (score 0):

`current` has type `taskPtr`, and `current->link` has type `list*`. You can't assign one to the other. A possible fix would be to change the type of the member variable `link` to `task*`, as mentioned by @Fareanor.

Unless this project's goal is to learn how to implement your own linked lists, I strongly recommend that you avoid doing exactly that, and use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead:

```
struct task {
    string taskDue;
    ...
    string year;
};

std::list<task> tasks;
```

Then adding a task is simply:

```
tasks.emplace_back(addTaskDue, addTaskDesc, ...);
```

Also note that it's not very efficient to store dates as strings. Consider using a suitable type from [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) instead.

There are a lot of helpful things in the [C++ standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp); it is worthwhile to spend some time to get familiar with it so you don't reinvent the wheel all the time, and so you can focus on the higher level details of implementing a todo list.

Comment: I think OP's error is essentially a typo.

Comment: Unless you are implementings a library, the purpose of implementing a linked list is never to produce a linked list, it is to practice the basics of data structures and pointers. You can't learn that by using a library, just like you can't learn how to cook by sitting at home ordering deliveries.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sure, but if you cook you can do so with pots, pans, knives and ingredients you ordered, you don't have to make everything from scratch. OP says he has a "ToDo list project", not a "learning the basics of data structures and pointers project".

Comment: Been out of school a while? Many assignments that force you to use a data structure that you are expected to write from scratch have some veneer of "real world" use applied to them. That's a poor argument. The safe assumption is that if someone is writing a list from scratch, it's because they have to, typically for an assignment. As it stands, I consider this a non-answer since it doesn't address the question being asked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just a glimps on what code would look like without your home brew list :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <list>
#include <string>

// using namespace std; <== NO

// a task is just that, it isn't the linked list so should not have any list info in it, like a next pointer
struct task final
{
    task() = default;

    task(const std::string& new_due, const std::string& new_desc, const& std::string new_course, const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& new_time) :
        due{ new_due },
        desc{ new_desc },
        course{ new_course },
        time{ new_time }
    {
    }

    ~task() = default;
    
    task(const task&) = default; // default copyable
    task& operator=(const task&) = default; // default copy assignable
    task(task&& task) = default; // default movable
    task& operator=(task&&) = default; // default move assignable

    std::string due; // no need to repeat name of struct in members
    std::string desc;
    std::string course;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time; // use chrono for times
};

// print by due etc will need to be free functions, it is not the task of a task
// to know how to print itself. And if you have a list, you can use std::sort(tasks.begin(),task.end(),sort_function) to sort in any order you like
// before doing a print.

int main()
{
    std::list<task> tasks;

    // this is how easy it can be to add a task to a list 
    tasks.emplace_back("new due", "new desc", "new course", std::chrono::system_clock::now()); // will call constructor for task.
}
```

Comment: i have a new issue after accordingly updated my code is the error "Error C2661 'task::task': no overloaded function takes 6 arguments ToDo experiment C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xmemory 682"

even if I run your code given code it still presented the same error.

Comment: This should have the Rule of 0 applied, as all task data is capable of managing itself just fine.

Comment: @sweenish Correct :)

Comment: So why write out destructor, etc.? It's just noise.

Comment: Haha "muscle memory" for making things explicit I guess. I had to write so many classes where I needed to make an explicit choice wether or not to support copy/move. That I just start typing the boilerplate. So it is good of you to give feedback this is not needed if everything is default.